# Dropdown not toggling in click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

This seems simple enough but I do not know what I am missing.

I have this dropdown

```
<div class="col-3">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick=openPayment() class="dropdown__btn"><span class="fas fa-book mr-2"></span>My Lessons<i class=" ml-2 fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  <div id="PaymentDropdown" class="dropdown__content">
    <a href="#">Math</a>
    <a href="#">Science</a>
    <a href="#">History</a>
    <a href="#">English</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css for that dropdown.

```
 .dropdown{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown__btn{
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown__btn:hover, .dropdown__btn:focus{
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown__content{
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown__content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown__content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:show;}
```

Now in my .dropdown__content class I have it displayed none in the css
This div also shares an id with "PaymentDropdown"

I built this function to toggle the hidden menu to show and hide but it does not seem to work. This code follows the same implementation in w3 schools so I an not sure what I am missing.

```
 function openPayment() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown__content').classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, use an index to get the actual DOM element.
2. `display: show` isn't valid CSS. You can use inline-block, inline, block, table-cell, etc...

Here's a working snippet.

```js
function openPayment() {
  var content1 = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown__content')[0];
  content1.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
 .dropdown{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown__btn{
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown__btn:hover, .dropdown__btn:focus{
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown__content{
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown__content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown__content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="openPayment()" class="dropdown__btn"><span class="fas fa-book mr-2"></span>My Lessons<i class=" ml-2 fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  <div id="PaymentDropdown" class="dropdown__content">
    <a href="#">Math</a>
    <a href="#">Science</a>
    <a href="#">History</a>
    <a href="#">English</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no value `show` for the `display` css property. Try with:

```
.show {
 display:block;
}
```

Also as Tobiq has mentioned - `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Either use jquery and set the class to all the elements, or select an index from the array and set it on the specific element.

Comment: This isn't a solution. You've spotted a mistake that you could have mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Sorry that I did not copied his entire code, made a change consisting of 1 word, and then post it as an answer, pretending to be more complete than just pointing to the exact problem...

Comment: I explained the problem, before posting a working solution as an example (obviously based upon his code). Also, suggesting to use jquery is not a solution, and is unnecessary.

Comment: I have no intentions to waste my time arguing with you. post your answer and live your life

Comment: You seem pretty IRATE.